# Android: background listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview

How can I change the background of a single cell of a ListView?
I wrote in java:

```
n_list = new ListView(this);
n_list.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.list_pressed));
```

This way changes the background of the whole list. When I press on a cell it changes the background of all cells.

`list_pressed.xml` on drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 

    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/listviewpress" />

    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/listviewpress" />
    <item 
          android:drawable="@drawable/listview" />
</selector>
```

How can I fix this?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: check this [**series of ListView tutorials**](http://www.technotalkative.com/category/android/listview/), go in bottom to top matter. You will be confident enough to build ListView next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [Custom Adapter](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) and in the `getView()` you can say what color you want to give to your row.

If you follow the tutorial on the link you can do on your `convertView` a `setBackground()` with the color you want. If you want a specific position just do an if before that `setBackground` .

Answer (score 1):

Below are few URL to have listview with customadapter so that you can set background to rows in getVIew()::

[LINL1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)

[LINK2](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)

[LINK3](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

[LINK4](http://geekswithblogs.net/bosuch/archive/2011/01/31/android---create-a-custom-multi-line-listview-bound-to-an.aspx)

[LINK5](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/183608/Android-Lists-ListActivity-and-ListView-II-Custom)